# Non square spiral matrix not printing correctly

Tags: c#, matrix, spiral

I am having issues with this assignment I have. I am to print a spiral matrix which cannot be square, in other words the user should input the number of rows and columns.

```
        Console.Write("Enter n: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter m: ");
        int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[,] matrix = new int[n,m];
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        string direction = "right";
        int maxRotations = n * m;

        for (int i = 1; i <= maxRotations; i++)
        {
            if (direction == "right" && (col > n - 1 || matrix[row, col] != 0))
            {
                direction = "down";
                col--;
                row++;
            }
            if (direction == "down" && (row > n - 1 || matrix[row, col] != 0))
            {
                direction = "left";
                row--;
                col--;
            }
            if (direction == "left" && (col < 0 || matrix[row, col] != 0))
            {
                direction = "up";
                col++;
                row--;
            }

            if (direction == "up" && row < 0 || matrix[row, col] != 0)
            {
                direction = "right";
                row++;
                col++;
            }

            matrix[row, col] = i;

            if (direction == "right")
            {
                col++;
            }
            if (direction == "down")
            {
                row++;
            }
            if (direction == "left")
            {
                col--;
            }
            if (direction == "up")
            {
                row--;
            }
        }

        // displej matrica

        for (int r = 0; r < n; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < m ; c++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,4}", matrix[r,c]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

My issue currently is that is not printing and at the same is printing in a spiral. In other words the spiral is kind of messed up. 
If i run the code and enter 4 as the number of rows and 6 as the number of columns I get the following:

```
1  2  3  4 0 24
12 13 14 5 0 23
11 16 17 18 19 22
10  9  8  7 20 21
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are not starting in the center of the array for a start

Comment: I think `if (direction == "right" && (col > n - 1 || matrix[row, col] != 0))` should be `if (direction == "right" && (col > m - 1 || matrix[row, col] != 0))` ( **m** instead of n)

Comment: @YairHalberstadt I guess the spiral is going "inward" not "outward".

Comment: @Fildor. if you start at 0,0 you can't have a spiral matrix without going out the bounds of the array!

Comment: @YairHalberstadt How do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: I think @Fildor is right. just changing `n` for `m` in the first `if` should work just fine

Comment: draw it. 0,0=1 0,1=2, 1,1=3, 1,0=4, 1,-1=5

Comment: Ah its going inwards not outwards! Just got what you meant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two conditions check the same boundary (n):

```
if (direction == "right" && (col > n - 1 || matrix[row, col] != 0))
if (direction == "down" && (row > n - 1 || matrix[row, col] != 0))
```

I guess for "right" your boundary should be `m`.

```
if (direction == "right" && (col > m - 1 || matrix[row, col] != 0))
```

That's why it is "turning" early: n is 4. And that's exactly where it is turning. The rest are all follow-up errors.

Comment: It might have been more obvious if the OP had named the variables r & c instead of n & m.

Comment: @spodger In fact I don't consider "r" and "c" much of an improvement to "n" and "m". But you can really break into terrible fights over var names. If I had to make a suggestion, I would have named them "maxRow" and "maxCol". But that is only my personal flavor. Or maybe "Width" and "Height" ...

Comment: That's it. Thanks a bunch to all :)

Comment: @Fildor, agree with maxCol and maxRow. I didn't think hard enough. :-)